# Java Unparseable date: different number of characters in ms value

Tags: java, date-format

I have a workflow where I need to take a date value as input, edit it and pass to output in exact format.
In order to manage this task, I use this:

```
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
 df.setTimeZone(tz);
 long date = df.parse(inputDate).getTime() + 1;
 outputDate = df.format(date).toString();
```

Most of a time this piece of code works just fine. However, sometimes I get input date like this:

```
2016-05-25T22:00:10.6Z
```

Please notice the number of characters for ms, it's 1 instead of 3.

In cases like above, I get the exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-05-25T22:00:10.6Z"
            at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

There's no way for me to affect the input date, but I need exactly three numbers in ms part. How do I gain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the ParseException and parse the Date using:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SXXX");
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SXXX");

    df.setTimeZone(tz);
    df2.setTimeZone(tz);

    long date;
    String dateToParse = "2016-05-25T22:00:10.6Z";
    try {
        date = df.parse(dateToParse).getTime() + 1;
    }catch (ParseException e){
        System.out.println("exception");
        date = df2.parse(dateToParse).getTime() + 1;

    }
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For parsing, actually you can specify only one letter (for each field) like this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SX");
// "2016-5-25T22:0:10.6Z" input is acceptable
// "2016-05-25T22:00:10.6Z" input is acceptable
// "2016-05-25T22:00:10.678Z" input is NOT acceptable
```

It accepts more than one digit (for each field) while parsing; which means the number of pattern letters is not significant *for parsing* (but it is significant *for formatting*). So, an input like `"2016-05-25T22:00:10.6Z"` is acceptable for the pattern above.

However, it seems there is some implementation problem in Java 8 (which I don't know exactly) or maybe there is something not documented, so that consecutive millisecond and timezone in pattern (eg. `SX` or `SSSX`) is not *that simple*. I mean `"2016-05-25T22:00:10.678Z"` is not acceptable by the pattern above, while nonconsecutive one is acceptable, like this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.S X"); // notice the space
// "2016-5-25T22:0:10.6 Z" input is acceptable
// "2016-05-25T22:00:10.6 Z" input is acceptable
// "2016-05-25T22:00:10.678 Z" input is acceptable
```

The workaround is, if your input has consecutive millisecond and timezone (no space between), create multiple `DateFormat` and catch the exception.

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SX");
DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SSX");
DateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d'T'H:m:s.SSSX");
try {
    result = df1.parse(inputDate); // first attempt
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    try {
        result = df2.parse(inputDate); // second attempt
    } catch (ParseException e2) {
        result = df3.parse(inputDate); // last attempt, dead if fails
    }
}
```

Yes, this workaround is *a kind of dirt* :D.